# Sonar is throwing a bug Format specifier should be used instead of string concatenation for the code - return String.format("%-" + size + "s", str);

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying to write the code return String.format("%-" + dsize + "s", str); in java but sonar is giving "Format specifier should be used instead of string concatenation for the code"

Comment: Then Sonar is an idiot.  Your code is fine for constructing a format with a field width specified at run time. You could do the same thing using String.format to construct the format to use in the given String.format, but that seems like writing less clear code to satisfy poor advice from a tool that is supposed to help.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be such a rule among Sonar's set of rules: see https://rules.sonarsource.com/java .

This is probably a custom rule. There are often advantages to using a format specifier instead of concatenation (greater flexibility, easier internationalization, etc. at the expense of static type safety and performance). However, in your situation, concatenation is better than using a format. Therefore, you should talk to the team at your organization that is responsible for static code analysis enforcement, and ask them to add an exception for your code.